# Adjust gap between menu

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, space

I'm trying to adjust the spacing(gap) between menu so it'll fit with the navbar.By changing margin doesn't seems to do it. Anyone have idea on how to fix this ? Is it possible to re-position each menu individually ?

[Here's the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d91jbfcy/)

```css
#navbar {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 180px;
    background: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/5cygax.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#menu {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 65px 50px 0px 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    background: #8495F5;
}

#menu,
#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#menu: li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
    perspective: 1000px;
}

#menu: li:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    position: inherit;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 1);
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    background: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu: li:hover>a {
    background: #333;
    color: rgba(0, 223, 252, 1);
    text-shadow: none;
}

#menu li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
    padding: 5px 0;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    animation-name: swingdown;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes swingdown {
    0% {
        opacity: .99999;
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
    }
    30% {
        transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(5deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    65% {
        transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(-3deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(0);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
}

#menu li li a {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ddd;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-top: dotted 1px transparent;
    border-bottom: dotted 1px transparent;
    transition: all .15s linear;
}

#menu li li a:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 223, 252, 1);
    border-top: dotted 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
    border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
    background: rgba(0, 223, 252, .02);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="navbar">

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a class="register" href="#">Register</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a class="guide" href="#">Guide</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quest & Event Guide</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brigand & T-map Guide</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a class="download" href="#">Download</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Patch Download</a></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I am guessing you want something like this?
The last lines in the CSS will control each LI position.

SOURCE:

```css
#navbar{
 width: 1200px;
 height: 180px;
    background: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/5cygax.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

ul#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 65px 0 0px 195px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
    list-style-type:none;
 }

 ul#menu, ul#menu-sub {
  list-style-type: none;
 }

ul#menu > li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15), 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  background: #8495F5;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25);
    border-radius: 8px;
 }

 #menu li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1), 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.25);
 }

 #menu a.menu-top {
  display: block;
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(75,75,75,1);
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  background: transparent;  
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
 
 }
 #menu-sub  {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
 }
 #menu-sub a {
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: none;
  border-top: dotted 1px transparent;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px transparent;
  transition: all .15s linear;
    padding: 10px;
    display:block;
 }

 #menu-sub a:hover {
  color: rgba(0,223,252,1);
  border-top: dotted 1px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(255,255,255,.15);
  background: rgba(0,223,252,.02);
 }
 #menu-sub li:hover > a {
  background: #333;
  color: rgba(0,223,252,1);
  text-shadow: none;
 }
 #menu li:hover #menu-sub {
  
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #333;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  animation-name: swingdown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;

 }

 @keyframes swingdown {
  0% {
   opacity: .99999;
   transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }

  30% {   
   transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(5deg);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  65% {
   transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(-3deg);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  100% {
   transform: rotateX(0);
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
 }

/* controlling each li's position */
ul#menu li:nth-child(1) { /*first */
  margin-right: 3%
}
ul#menu li:nth-child(2) { /*first */
  margin-right: 200px;
}
ul#menu li:nth-child(3) { /*first */
  margin-right: 3%
}
ul#menu li:nth-child(4) { /*first */
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navbar">
   <ul id="menu">
         <li><a class="menu-top home" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-top register" href="#">Register</a></li>
         <li>
                <a class="menu-top guide" href="#">Guide</a>
             <ul id="menu-sub">
                    <li><a href="#">New Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quest & Event Guide</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brigand & T-map Guide</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="menu-top download" href="#">Download</a>
           <ul id="menu-sub">
             <li><a href="#">Patch Download</a></li>
           </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

View Pen: [Adjust gap between menu](https://codepen.io/martink/pen/qmyGWN/)

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: Updated pen (last lines css), so the LI css dont affect the submenus like it did

Answer (score 0):

Changed margin for #menu

```
#menu {
  margin: 65px 0 0px 20px;
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 180px;
  background: url(http://i67.tinypic.com/5cygax.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 65px 0 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background: #8495F5;
}

#menu,
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu: li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#menu: li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
  box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 1);
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  background: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu: li:hover>a {
  background: #333;
  color: rgba(0, 223, 252, 1);
  text-shadow: none;
}

#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#menu li:hover ul {
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #333;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  animation-name: swingdown;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes swingdown {
  0% {
    opacity: .99999;
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(5deg);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  65% {
    transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(-3deg);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
}

#menu li li a {
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: none;
  border-top: dotted 1px transparent;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px transparent;
  transition: all .15s linear;
}

#menu li li a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 223, 252, 1);
  border-top: dotted 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  border-bottom: dotted 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
  background: rgba(0, 223, 252, .02);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navbar">

    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a class="register" href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a class="guide" href="#">Guide</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">New Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Quest & Event Guide</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Brigand & T-map Guide</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>

    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a class="download" href="#">Download</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Patch Download</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to adjust the spacing(gap) between menu so it'll fit with the navbar. Duh, does it look fine to you ?